# Is facebook returns error for interest fields if response size is big?

Tags: facebook

I am using v1 fb api and last night facebook started to return me the following for interest fields like music,movies,books..

{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unknown error has occurred.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 1
  }
}

If i delete all music in my fb account, it works fine. Anyone has seen the same issue before?

Comment: I am also experiencing this with one of my users. It started occurring since the push last night (10 hours ago). Requests fail when requesting music or movies with 500 HTTP and the same as above. I think its a server side issue with their new code.

Comment: If it just started file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/251759635025024/ @Neonkoala please subscribe

Answer (score 0):

Accepted as a Facebook bug:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/251759635025024/

Thanks hgoz.